# Android Studio - App crashes after adding second activity

Tags: android

I'm doing my first Android app. When I run my application on my Galaxy S4 which is connected with an USB cable it crashes. Before adding the second Activity it doesn't crashes.

My Code including logcat: http://pastebin.com/JMKpY859

I also added this code to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityByDate"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_by_date" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Where is your LogCat outputs

Comment: It is in the pastbin link here you have the direct link: http://pastebin.com/s4wAshVn

Comment: I didnt find your code

Comment: If you open this link: http://pastebin.com/JMKpY859 you will see my two activity classes the xml's and the catlog. Sorry for doing it so complicated but I didn't find out how to add a spoiler or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, by looking into your logcat, it shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.motorsportcalendar.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
```

And based in the [answer of user3475933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179076/android-studio-app-crashes-after-adding-second-activity/28179360#28179360), I suppose you're writing:

```
button_m_date.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
```

I suppose that you're trying to add a button in the view, and a listener onClick to it. Isn't it? The problem comes when you call **setOnClickListener** passing **this** as parameter, but **this** refers to the current class (that extends from **Activity**). **Activity** is the class that manages the whole view and cannot be used as a listener because it is not a **view**. So, to correct your lines, write something like this:

```
Button button_m_date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.<you_button_id>);
button_m_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // action instructions here...
    }
});
```

Note that you even do not need to create a named listener. It can be created anonymously within the **setOnClickListener** method.

=> Your fault is that you're trying to cast **View.OnClickListener** into **Activity**:

```
(View.OnClickListener) this
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid complex coding patterns. Try the following code snippet inside `onCreate()`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityByDate.class));
            finish();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

instead of using :

**button_m_date.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);**

**button_m_series.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);**

use only :

**button_m_date.setOnClickListener(this);**

**button_m_series.setOnClickListener(this);**